# How to make this jtable value saved in database when it is edited?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This code will display all record from my table.
When record is displayed i want to be editable.
When any record is edited it should be saved in database.
Please guys any help will do.

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class user_list2 extends JFrame
{
    Container con;

    int rows=0;
    Object data1[][];   
    JScrollPane scroller;
    JTable table;


    user_list2()
    {
        con=getContentPane();
        con.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(800,600);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Connection conn;
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ce)
        {System.out.println("error");}

        try
        {
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:abc");  
            st=conn.createStatement();  
            rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Patients Where Status='Discharged' ");

            while(rs.next())
            {

                rows++;
            }



                data1=new Object[rows][10];     Object[] Colheads={"Patients Name","Age", "Sex","Admit Date","Description","Reference","No Of Dependent","Status","Type Of Room","ID"};
                rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from Patients Where Status='Discharged' ");
                for(int i1=0;i1<rows;i1++)
                {
                    rs.next();
                    for(int j1=0;j1<10;j1++)
                    {
                        data1[i1][j1]=rs.getString(j1+1);
                    }
                }
                JTable table=new JTable(data1,Colheads);


                int v=ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED;
                int h=ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED;
                JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane(table,v,h);


                con.add(jsp);


            }
        catch(SQLException ss)
        {

        System.out.println("error"+ss);
        ss.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] ar)
    {

        user_list2 obj=new user_list2();
        obj.setSize(900,600);       
        obj.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

use TableModelListener to listen state change of the table.and implement `tableChanged` method.

```
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);

public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

//write your db code to update

}
```